# How to run code in your main view controller in swift when a pop up closes

Tags: swift, popup

I'm currently writing my first swift app. Currently there is one view/view controller that loads when the app is run as well as a popup window tied to a separate view-controller (like so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5i8n_bqblE). When I close the pop-up I want to update several things on my original view and run some code. However, neither func viewDidLoad() nor func viewDidAppear() seems to run. And I can't do anything from the pop-up view since I don't have access to the components in the main view-controller from it. What should I do?

The pop-up is "presented modally" if that makes a difference?

Comment: Your `viewWillAppear` would get called here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but viewWillAppear does not seem to run either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a MainViewController from which you're presenting the PopupVC. You can use delegate pattern here.
Define a PopupVCDelegate as follow

```
protocol PopupVCDelegate {
    func popupDidDisappear()
}
```

In your PopupVC define a `delegate` property of type `PopupVCDelegate`. And in the `closePopup` method, call the delegate method `popupDidDisappear`

```
class PopupVC: UIViewController {
    public var delegate: PopupVCDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func closePopup(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        delegate?.popupDidDisappear()
    }
}
```

Now any class that adopts this `delegate` will be able to receive the callback when the `closePopup` is called. So make your MainViewController to adopt this delegate.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, PopupVCDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func showPopup() {
        let popupViewController = //Instantiate your popup view controller
        popupViewController.delegate = self
        //present your popup
    }

    func popupDidDisappear() {
        //This method will be called when the popup is closed
    }
}
```

Another way is to fire a notification through `NSNotificationCenter` on `closePopup` and add an observer in MainViewController to listen to that notification. But it is not recommended in this scenario.

## Edit

As you have asked for the NSNotificationCenter method. Please change your classes as follow

```
class PopupVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func closePopup(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("notificationClosedPopup"), object: nil)
    }
}  
class MainViewController: UIViewController, PopupVCDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onPopupClosed), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationClosedPopup"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func onPopupClosed() {
        //This method will be called when the popup is closed
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationClosedPopup"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, when I add this to my code the line "popupViewController.delegate = self" yields the error message "Variable used within its own initial value"

Comment: Also, even if you advise against the second method (of using NSNotificationCenter on ClosePopup) I would be grateful for information  (from you or someone else knowledgeble) on how to implement this.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include NSNotificationCenter method. You can use that method to receive a notification when the popup is closed.

Comment: As for your "Variable used within its own initial value" error message, I think you are assigning 'self' to delegate in 'init' method, and 'self' is not fully initialized at that time. If that is the case then you can move your code to viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, the error message persists after i moved the code. The second method is error free though! Unfortunately "onPopupClosed()" doesn't run. Can this be related to the popup being presented modally?

Comment: My mistake! (pertaining to how i implemented your suggestion in my code.) It works! It works! Thank you! Hugs!