# How to call a method when an iOS UINavigationController has been popped?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have an iOS `UINavigationController` whose `rootViewController` is `ViewController1`. `ViewController1` pushes `ViewController2` by calling `pushViewController(_:animated:)`, and then `ViewController2` pops itself by calling `popViewController(animated:)`. I am not using a storyboard.

Now that I have arrived back in `ViewController1`, I would like `ViewController1` to do something automatically.

How can I arrange to have a method of `ViewController1` called when we have returned there from `ViewController2`? In other words, how can `ViewController1` sense that it has just been uncovered? I know I can do this by calling the `navigationController(_:didShow:animated:)` method of a `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: The same question is available on the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259336/how-to-run-code-in-your-main-view-controller-in-swift-when-a-pop-up-closes of the StackOverflow.They have used the protocol-delegate callback method, to invoke the V1 after the V2 popped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run code in your main view controller in swift when a pop up closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259336/how-to-run-code-in-your-main-view-controller-in-swift-when-a-pop-up-closes)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a protocol that lets you notify ViewController1 when ViewController2 is dismissed, somewhat like this:

```
protocol FeedbackDelegate: class {
    func shouldDoSomething()
}

class ViewController1: UIViewController, FeedbackDelegate {
    func thisIsWhereYouPresentVC2() {
        let vc = ViewController2()
        vc.feedbackDelegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    // MARK: - FeedbackDelegate
    func shouldDoSomething() {
    }
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    weak var feedbackDelegate: FeedbackDelegate?
    
    func thisIsWhereYouDismissVC2() {
        self.feedbackDelegate?.shouldDoSomething()
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```